# Haskell cabal-install errors

Tags: haskell, package, cabal, cabal-install

I am having lots of problems with `cabal-install`:
1: Every time  I  do `cabal update`, it tells me to do `cabal install cabal-install`, so I do, and then when I do `cabal update` again, it says the same thing.

2: When I try to install `ghc-mod` from hackage, it gives me this error:

```
[username@arch ~]$ cabal install ghc-mod
In order, the following will be installed:
haskell-src-exts-1.14.0 (reinstall) changes: pretty-1.1.1.1 -> 1.1.1.0
hlint-1.8.55 (reinstall)
ghc-mod-3.1.4
setup: The program happy version >=1.17 is required but it could not be found.
ghc-mod-3.1.4 depends on haskell-src-exts-1.14.0 which failed to install.
haskell-src-exts-1.14.0 failed during the configure step.
hlint-1.8.55 depends on haskell-src-exts-1.14.0 which failed to install.
```

So the problem was `The program happy version >=1.17 is required but it could not be found.`, so I installed `happy 1.19.2` using `cabal install happy` without problems.

I tried `cabal install ghc-mod` again, same error, so I tried `cabal install haskell-src-exts --reinstall --force-reinstalls`. It gave me the following error:

```
[username@arch ~]$ cabal install haskell-src-exts --reinstall --force-reinstalls
Configuring haskell-src-exts-1.14.0...
setup: The program happy version >=1.17 is required but it could not be found.
Failed to install haskell-src-exts-1.14.0
cabal: Error: some packages failed to install:
haskell-src-exts-1.14.0 failed during the configure step. The exception was:
ExitFailure 1
```

Basically `The program happy version >=1.17 is required but it could not be found.`. So happy is the problem again?

I have also tried downloading the tar.gz files from hackage and using `cabal install` on the
`.cabal` file, also modified the `.cabal` file to ignore dependencies, still failed.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

`cabal install` places executables in `~/.cabal/bin`.

If you add it to your path, you will be able to use the new executables installed by cabal:

```
$ PATH=$HOME/.cabal/bin:$PATH
```

Comment: Amazing. I just encountered two really weird things, so I write here in the case it would help someone. The first: I already had the `$HOME/.cabal/bin` in my $PATH, and… it didn't work! That only start working after I replaced the `$HOME` with `~` — really funny, because I used the variable being afraid that tilde won't work. The second thing: even after the system saw the path, and the *happy* — the *cabal* still didn't! Only after I executed the command from this answer, it start working. My guess is that *cabal* don't understand tilde either…

Comment: So, I guess the problem is like this: *cabal* wants a full path. So, after I added in my `/etc/environment` in the $PATH the `:$HOME/.cabal/bin` *(either the variant with tilde)*, the *cabal* in both cases thinks that *tilde* or the *$HOME* is part of the path *(it is valid path either)*. To get it working one have to write into the `/etc/environment` the full path till the directory with binaries.

Answer (score 23):

I encountered with same problem and I solved the problem with installing `happy` package(confusing package name). So install it with your package manager(apt-get, pacman etc) before install package with cabal. This should be fix the problem.

Comment: On a clean install from source of GHC/cabal (no Haskell Platform), installing this fixed a nondescript `ExitFailure 1` failure.

Comment: I was able to fix this by `cabal install happy`.

Comment: Installing with package manager messed things up in the past for me on Ubuntu. The big problem is apt-get installs one kind of Haskell module but then you start using cabal and you get different versions of the module. Dependency hell conflicts. So the suggestion by @connorbode is best. Using cabal gives you the latest, synchronized version.